# Why does (function() { ... }()) create "singleton" state?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following two functions,

```
// function 
var returnObject = function() { 
  var values = []; 

  return {
    sum: function(addend) { 
      var toReturn = 0;
      if (addend) {
        values.push(addend);
      }
      values.forEach(function(el) {
        toReturn += el; 
      });
      return toReturn;
    }
  }
};  

// immediately executed function 
var returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction = (function() { 
  var values = []; 

  return {
    sum: function(addend) { 
      var toReturn = 0;
      if (addend) {
        values.push(addend);
      }
      values.forEach(function(el) {
        toReturn += el; 
      });
      return toReturn;
    }
  }
}());
```

I'm having an "eeeergh! brain!" moment at this point about this, but I don't understand why the `returnObject` returns a unique closure state every time it's used, but `returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction` returns the same state.

Consider the output of the following:

```
var summer1 = returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction; 
summer1.sum(2); 
summer1.sum(4); 
summer1.sum(8);
console.log(summer1.sum()); 

var summer2 = returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction; 
summer2.sum(2); 
summer2.sum(4); 
summer2.sum(8);
console.log(summer2.sum()); 

var summer3 = returnObject(); 
summer3.sum(2); 
summer3.sum(4); 
summer3.sum(8);
console.log(summer3.sum());

var summer4 = returnObject(); 
summer4.sum(2); 
summer4.sum(4); 
summer4.sum(8);
console.log(summer4.sum());
```

Output:

```
14
28 // why not 14? 
14 
14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially, your `returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction` is a reference to a *single invocation* of the enclosed state, therefore each use of that reference will access the same state.

Otherwise, each call to `returnObject` makes a new invocation of the returned function and its enclosed state.

Note that your `returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction` is also semantically equivalent to:

```
var returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction = returnObject();
```

i.e. it's just an instance itself.  So given:

```
var summer1 = returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction;
var summer2 = returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction;
var summer3 = returnObject();
var summer4 = returnObject();
```

It should be trivially observed that `summer1` and `summer2` are *the same instance*.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to see by anotating where objects/scopes are created and used :

```
returnObject = ... /* No scope created, just a function is given a name */
returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction = ... /* Create scope A */

var summer1 = returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction;  /*A*/
summer1.sum(2); /*A*/
summer1.sum(4); /*A*/
summer1.sum(8); /*A*/
console.log(summer1.sum()); /*A*/

var summer2 = returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction; /*Still A*/
summer2.sum(2); /*Still A*/
summer2.sum(4); /*Still A*/
summer2.sum(8);/*Still A*/
console.log(summer2.sum()); /*Still A*/

var summer3 = returnObject(); /* Create scope B */
summer3.sum(2); /*B*/
summer3.sum(4); /*B*/
summer3.sum(8); /*B*/
console.log(summer3.sum()); /*B*/

var summer4 = returnObject(); /* Create scope C */
summer4.sum(2); /*C*/
summer4.sum(4); /*C*/
summer4.sum(8); /*C*/
console.log(summer4.sum()); /*C*/
```

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you have a function that returns an object when you call it.

With `returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction` you run the function once (creating one object) and then you do a bunch of different things to the object (which isn't a function), including copying it from `summer1` to `summer2`, that you store in `returnImmediatelyExecutedFunction`.

With `returnObject`, you run the function twice, and do a bunch of different things to two different objects.